# DevExpress.Web.v13.1 configuration error in deploying in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have a problem regarding on deploying my website with a third party control which is `DevExpress.Web.v13.1`. I googled same problem but found nothing. How come that it worked locally and when I deploy it, it gives me an error. I'm new to this so bear with me. You can check the error from this [**link**](http://rollymorales-001-site1.smarterasp.net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means it cannot find the devexpress asp.net assemblies. I recommend using the BIN deploy method as shown in this short video: https://www.youtube.com/embed/menrUfZNoR0

Also, contact the support@devexpress.com team as they're great and you'll likely get an answer faster there.

Answer (score 0):

So, on reading the error page, I see that the error is, "The system cannot find the file specified.". Since it is the first assembly in the assembly list, I would guess that the other assemblies mentioned won't be found either. I would guess then that the assembly (or assemblies) has not been deployed to the site, whereas, locally, the installer made sure the web site could locate the assemblies.

Since I have no way of knowing how you deployed your site that's about as far as I can go. I would certainly recommend you read the [Troubleshooting Guide](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument14777).

Also, I'm really curious as to why you didn't contact DevExpress Support directly? Support is available with your license...

Cheers, Julian